# How to get Hour from Timestamps ending in Z?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The timestamps my database returns are in this format:

```
'2022-11-25T17:54:29.819Z'
```

I want to do hour(timestamp) to return just the hour but get this error

```
'error:"function hour(timestamp with time zone) does not exist"'
```

How do I get around this? Thanks!

Comment: Reading the docs [Date.time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function [`extract(...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```sql
select extract(hour from my_column) from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `EXTRACT` for that:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM yourtimestamp) FROM yourtable;
```

Whether a Z occurs in the timestamp, doesn't matter, see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6EB0wdb3)

See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)